# How can I get kwargs values in redirected view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send user to "payment view" after user register. here is what i try:

```
def dispatch():
                ......
                #user registration code ...
                #then i want to send email to redirected page
                new_user_email =form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                print("user registration complete")

            else:
                message = form.errors
                messages.error(request, message)
                print('form not verified '+ str(form.errors))
            
            return redirect(reverse('account:payment'),kwargs = {'email': new_user_email})
```

url:

```
path('payment/', views.PaymentView.as_view(), name = 'payment'),
```

and after go to payment view i want to get email in this view.

```
class PaymentView(TemplateView):
    '''
    For Payment related information and proceed to get new subscription.
    '''
    template_name = 'home/payment.html'

    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwarg):
        context =  super().get_context_data(*args, **kwarg)
        .... 
        # here i need email
        # context['email'] = 
        return context
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the email in query parameter which can be used in the context of the redirected view.

In your registration view:

```
return redirect(reverse('account:payment') + '?email=' + new_user_email)
```

This will create the url: `/payment/?email=<<email>>`

In the context of the next view, you can access the query parameter like so:

```
def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwarg):
        context =  super().get_context_data(*args, **kwarg)
        .... 
        # here i need email
        context['email'] = self.request.GET.get("email")
        return context
```

You can also login the user first. After signup, you can redirect the user to the view and simply use `request.user.email` to access the email. This way, it will be easier to manage payment from the user.